# Extracting from script - beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How would the value for the "tier1Category" be extracted from the source of this page? 
https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/walgreens-wal-zyr-24-hour-allergy-tablets/ID=prod6205762-product

```
soup.find('script')
```

returns only a subset of the source, and the following returns another source within that code.

```
json.loads(soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").text)
```

Comment: what would be the expected return value?

Comment: Medicines & Treatments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitto and I have similar approaches to this, however I prefer to not rely on knowing which script contains the matching pattern, nor the structure of the script.

```
import requests
from collections import abc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def nested_dict_iter(nested):
    for key, value in nested.items():
        if isinstance(value, abc.Mapping):
            yield from nested_dict_iter(value)
        else:
            yield key, value

r = requests.get('https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/walgreens-wal-zyr-24-hour allergy-tablets/ID=prod6205762-product')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if 'tier1Category' in script.text:
        j = json.loads(script.text[str(script.text).index('{'):str(script.text).rindex(';')])
        for k,v in list(nested_dict_iter(j)):
             if k == 'tier1Category':
                 print(v)
```

Comment: I haven't seen the function nested_dict_iter() used before.  Thanks for teaching me about this function.  I had to upvote this answer, because it was the cleanest.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I used to get the output

- use *find_all* and get the 10th script tag. This script tag contains the  `tier1Category` value.
- Get the script text from the first occurrence of `{` and till last occurrence of `;` . This will give us a proper *json* text.
- Load the text using `json.loads`
- Understand the structure of the *json* to find how to get the `tier1Category` value.

Code:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/walgreens-wal-zyr-24-hour-allergy-tablets/ID=prod6205762-product')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
script_text=soup.find_all('script')[9].text
start=str(script_text).index('{')
end=str(script_text).rindex(';')
proper_json_text=script_text[start:end]
our_json=json.loads(proper_json_text)
print(our_json['product']['results']['productInfo']['tier1Category'])
```

Output:

```
Medicines & Treatments
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an id. I assume tier 1 is after `shop` in the navigation tree. Otherwise, I don't see that value in that script tag. I see it in an ordinary script (without the script[type="application/ld+json"] ) tag but there are a lot of regex matches for tier 1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/walgreens-wal-zyr-24-hour-allergy-tablets/ID=prod6205762-product')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = soup.select_one("#bdCrumbDesktopUrls_0").text
print(data)
```

Comment: I have found this method to be useful, but my question is about extracting from the script tag. thanks!

Comment: It isn't in the json script tag. See my comment.

Comment: so there would be no way to get that value with bs?

Comment: I see it in an ordinary script tag but there are a lot of regex matches for tier 1

Comment: So, I would have thought my way is likely more reliable and easier.